# How to make a loop to take float input in a row?

Tags: c, loops, matrix, input

**Take Float Input in a Row With Tabs**
I want to take float input from the user a specific number of times in such a way that when the user presses the enter key, instead of going to the next line as scanf() automatically does, move the cursor one tab forward (\t).

Example:

 5 -4 8 75

 2 -7 4 11

Note: I'm using this code to get float values into an array for matrices.

I have tried a variation of the following:-

```
int i=0,interval=10;
float a[10]={0};

for (i=0;i<interval;i++)
{
    scanf("%f",a[i]);
    printf("\t");
    i++;
}
```

OR

```
int i=0;
float a[10]={0};

while (a[i]=getche()!='\r')
{
    printf("\t");
    i++;
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone helps me out.

Comment: Why don't you just type all the values for one row on one line, and press Enter once?

Comment: There isn't a portable way to do what you ask for, but what @WeatherVane suggested is what is common practice.

Comment: I know how that goes, thanks. What I intend to do is to ask the user how many rows and columns there are in a matrix and then make an array of that matrix and let the user input data into it. 
I don't want to use dozens of scanf() statements.

Comment: I intend to use nested loops with counter variables num_rows and num_columns.

Comment: Use `fgets()` to read _lines_.  Process those lines for `float`s and for a consistent number of `float`s.  No need to enter `column` beforehand.  Code could keep reading until an empty line signifying row completion.  Suggest to never use `scanf()`.

Comment: It makes no difference if they are requested in a loop or not. They can still be entered on one line.

Comment: Reading floats into an array of char won't work well.  Not passing a pointer to `scanf()` won't lead to happiness either.

Comment: @chux could you please tell me how to process fgets(string) for float?

Comment: Something like `p = string; int n; float f; while (sscanf(p, "%f %n", &f, &n)  == 1) { printf("%f\n", f); p += n;}  if (*p == 0) puts("Scanning ended without porblem");`

Answer (score 1):

If you were using windows, you can actually try:

```
#include <conio.h>
```

and:

```
char c[100];
int i = 0;
float f;
while ((c[i++]=getch())!='\t');
c[i++] = '\0';
f = atof(c);
```

Since `getch()` read characters instantly.

Comment: Interesting solution (albeit - as was commented - necessarily not portable). It needs some additional checks, for the total number of inputs and in case a user presses Enter too soon.